# Rails 4: nested forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have two models:

```
class Incident < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :person
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :person
end
```

and

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :incidents
    validates :name, presence: true
end
```

I would like that users will be able to create or not the person in the same incident's form.

My incident controller:

```
def new
    @incident = Incident.new
    @incident.build_person
end

def create
    @incident = Incident.new(incident_params)

    if @incident.save
        redirect_to event_path(params[:incident]["event_id"].to_i)
    else
        redirect_to events_path
    end
end

private

def incident_params

    params.require(:incident).permit(:incident_type_id, :event_id, :user_id, 
        :description, :supporter_id, :person_id, :supporter_group_id, 
        person_attributes: [:id, :name, :surname, :second_surname,    :identity_document])
end
```

When I save an incident with a person this code works. But when I want to save an incident without person, because it is not required, this code fails because it waits a person (`name can't be blank`). How I could save an incident without person?

Comment: Try using `accepts_nested_attributes_for :person, reject_if: lambda { |person| person.name.blank? }`

Comment: thanks MrYoshji, reject_if is the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :person, reject_if: :all_blank
```

This mean that ...

If you don't input all person attributes on incident new page, the Person model don't exec validitation and create only incident record.
If you input any person attribute, the Person model exec validitation and create incident and person record.

Comment: And If I create an incident without person and then I want update with a person...how I could do that? I added :id to strong params but person don't create in spite of server receive params. In update method I only have @incident = Incident.find(params[:id]) and @incident.update_attributes(incident_params)

Comment: If you just create person with updating incident in edit page, In edit method you should have @incident = Incident.find(params[:id]) and @incident.build_person unless @incident.person. If you select person in incident edit page, you should add select method to select one of people for incident. like below
`<%= f.select :person_id, Person.all.map { |p| [p.name, p.id] }, include_blank: true %>`